# Field with finite elements $\mathbb Z_{11}$ How to find multiplicative inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

$\mathbb Z_{11} = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 \}$

[image]

Above would be the tables

From the tables $Z_{11}$ is closed under addition and multiplication

Since the tables are symmetric both operations are commutative

Since addition and multiplication is in $\mathbb R$ this satisfies associative and distributive conditions, addition and multiplication in $Z_{11}$ will do.

The additive identity is 0 and multiplicative identity is 1

Additive inverse:

$0^{-1} = 0, 1^{-1} = 10, 2^{-1} = 9, 3^{-1} = 8, 4^{-1} = 7, 5^{-1} = 6, 6^{-1} = 5,  7^{-1} = 4, 8^{-1} = 3, 9^{-1}=2, 10^{-1} = 1$

Multiplicative inverse:

$1^{-1} = $

idk how to do this part

Comment: You could just look at the multiplication table on the top right, and notice that in every row except for the 0 row, there is a entry with the value 1.  The column index of the 1 in the $r$-th row is the multiplicative inverse of $r$.  Or, you could find out  a reason why for each $r\ne 0$ there exist integers $c$ and $d$ so that $cr = 1 + 11d$.  If you know this, then $c$ is the mod $11$ multiplicative inverse of $r$.

Comment: The multiplicative inverse of $x$ is the number "$x^{-1}$" such that $x\odot x^{-1}= 1$ where $1$ is the multiplicative identity and $\odot$ is the specific "multiplication" that we are using here.  For example $2\odot 6= 1$ so $2^{-1}=6$.

Comment: @kimchilover thank you

Comment: Fermat tells us that $a^{10} \equiv 1 \bmod 11$ and so $a^{-1}=a^9$.

Answer (score 1):

In the set $Z_{11}$, the multiplicative inverse of 2 is 6 because $2 \times 6 \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$. The multiplicative inverse of an element $a$ in a group is an element $b$ such that $a \times b \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$. In other words, the product of $a$ and its multiplicative inverse is congruent to 1 modulo 11.

In general, to find the multiplicative inverse of an element $a$ in $Z_{11}$, you can use the Extended Euclidean algorithm. This algorithm takes as input two integers $a$ and $b$, and returns the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$, as well as integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax + by = \gcd(a, b)$. If the greatest common divisor of $a$ and 11 is 1, then $a$ has an inverse modulo 11 and $x$ is the inverse. Otherwise, $a$ does not have an inverse modulo 11.